# Malicious backlinks from malware sites - what's their purpose?

Tags: seo, backlinks, negative-seo

I have two websites that have created dozens of backlinks to my website.  votefrankharris dot com and a similar ddswhite dot com.  The first website's backlinking pages redirect to malicious pages/sites.  The sites appear to no longer be in use (I guess Frank didn't get elected).  There's a fairly exhaustive list of these [spammy sites here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/36048251?hl=en).

My question is, what is the point of someone doing this?  Are they hoping that curious web admins will click on their backlinks and get infected?  Is this some kind of blackhat SEO trick?

Answer (score 1):

Raw access logs and/or summary statistics pages (generated by log analysers like Webalyzer, AWStats…) are sometimes, fortunately rarely, public on the web. This is often the result of a bad web server configuration. If those pages include the `referer` info in an `a href` tag, this makes public links for the backlinking spammy/malicious websites.

When the access to those logs and statistical pages is restricted, spammers hope that curious granted users (e.g., admins) will investigate the links and "eat the spam" or get infected.

This is called [referer spamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer_spam).